# Using CURL to scrape data from booking.com

Tags: php, curl

I dont understand why this code doesnt work, whenever I run it, it says the session has ended and that I need to reconnect. If you are wondering why im trying to scrape the admin panel is because I want to make a live and easily managable interface to store current bookings.

```
<?php
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';
$loginUrl = 'https://admin.booking.com/hotel/hoteladmin/login.html';
$cookie_file_path = "/tmp/cookies.txt";


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'loginname='.$username.'&password='.$password);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$store = curl_exec($ch);
$file = file_get_contents('https://admin.booking.com/hotel/hoteladmin/general/dashboard.html');
print_r($file);
?>
```

There are no cookie files generated either.

Comment: because f_g_c is completely separate from curl, and a cookie you get in curl is useless in f_g_c unless you add a lot of code to transfer them. Plus, you need to check the return value of curl_exec(). don't just assume the curl request succeeded. always check for failure, ESPECIALLY when you're dealing with external resources.

Comment: So what can I do to get the pages contents?

Comment: you started with curl, so stick with curl. just make another curl request to fetch the dashboard page. what you're doing is the equivalent of logging into a site with Chrome, and wondering why you're not logged in when you switch to Firefox.

Comment: I dont know how to use curl , the code is pretty much copy pasted so how would I go about fetching a page?

Comment: I tried printing what curl_exec returned and it showed nothing so I presume its not connecting?